# Why does Task.Run not allow me to include a method definition?

Tags: c#

I've got the following code.

```
Task.Run(() => StartAsync())

public void StartAsync() { }
```

Which works fine, but I want to supply a method definition instead.

```
Task.Run(StartAsync) // Compiler refuses this
```

The `ContinueWith` method allows method definitions, so I'm wondering why the `Run` method doesn't.

```
Task.Run(() => StartAsync()).ContinueWith(HandleException);

public void StartAsync() { }

public void HandleException(Task task) { }
```

Comment: What error message does the compiler give you? Is `StartAsync` overloaded?

Comment: `'void Observer.StartAsync()' has the wrong return type `; it is not overloaded

Comment: Note that although the answers there explain why you got the error, they do not show how to work around it. You can write `Task.Run(new Action(StartAsync))`, `Task.Run((Action)StartAsync)`, or `Task.Run(action: StartAsync)`.

Comment: There are 2 overloads of `Task.Run`. One with a `Func<Task>`, one taking an `Action` parameter. The compiler chooses the `Func<Task>` overload.

Comment: @hvd I never thought about using named parameters as hints for overload resolution. Nice idea.